# print in awk works as a command, but not in .bashrc

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am running the command `online | awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$10=$11=$12=""; print $0}'` and this command is working perfectly when I run it in the command line.  However, when I add it to my .bashrc file as an alias running the exact same command, upon reloading my .bashrc, I get the output:

`If 'print' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found print
-bash: print: command not found`

I would really like to use an alias for this command instead of running that long line every time.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried changing the print in the .bashrc to echo and printf but those changes do not fix the problem.

EDIT:  this is the corresponding line in my .bashrc:
`alias online="ps aux | grep -i -E "(rename|StrictHost)" | grep -v "grep" | sort -k9 -n | awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$10=$11=$12=""; print $0}'"`

Comment: Can you show us the line in `bashrc`? Have you escaped the single quotes?

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant content of your `.bashrc`. (Though in this case I can guess what you did wrong, because it's a common problem that's come up before.)

Comment: Did you put single-quotes around it in the `alias` command? There's no (direct) way to nest single-quotes inside a single-quoted string, so that's going to be complicated to get right.

Comment: Added the corresponding .bashrc line.

Comment: I fixed the initial error and now my .bashrc line looks like this: `alias online="ps aux | grep -i -E '(rename|StrictHost)' | grep -v 'grep' | sort -k9 -n | awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$10=$11=$12=""; print $0}'"`  But now I am getting this error: `awk: {=======0=1=2=; print -bash}
awk:  ^ syntax error`

Comment: This should work `alias foo='ps aux | grep -i -E "(rename|StrictHost)" | grep -v "grep" | sort -k9 -n | awk '"'"'{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$10=$11=$12=""; print $0}'"'"`

Comment: why not define a bash function instead? much more flexible. Good luck.